# How to define events dynamically in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, dynamic

I have more click events inside my view like

```
events:{
            'click #link1':'showDetails',
            'click #link2':'showDetails',
            'click #link3':'showDetails',
            'click #link4':'showDetails',
            'click #link5':'showDetails',
            'click #link6':'showDetails',
            'click #link7':'showDetails',
            'click #link8':'showDetails',
            'click #link9':'showDetails',
            'click #link10':'showDetails',
            'click #link11':'showDetails',
            'click #link12':'showDetails',
            'click #link13':'showDetails',
            'click #link14':'showDetails',
            'click #link15':'showDetails',
            'click #link16':'showDetails',
            'click #link17':'showDetails',
            'click #link18':'showDetails',
            'click #link19':'showDetails',
            'click #link20':'showDetails',
            'click #link21':'showDetails'
}
```

Is there any way to make it dynamic. Because the number of click events may increase in future.

Note: I can get those ids(#etox_link,etc) in an array.

please post your suggestions.

Comment: And I need to pass some parameters in the function call also.. :)

Comment: Use class and `data-*` attributes and make it dynamic. Do not repeat yourself.

Comment: I am unable to make it work. I dont know what i am missing??

 jsfiddle.net/keshav_1007/p10masvr/1 

I m getting uncaught exception.. please let me know what i am in missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do Something like this:

#### Single Event:

```
events:{
    'click .link':'showDetails',
}
```

#### function `showDetails`:

```
showDetails : function(e){
   var _type = $(e.target).attr("id").toUpperCase();
   var _callbackName = "show"+_type+"Details";
   if(typeof this[_callbackName] !== "function") return console.log("No callback named:",_callbackName);
   this[_callbackName].call(this,e);
},

showAESDetails : function(e){
   console.log("Do something!");
}
```

**Edited to respond to OP comment:** whit this procedure you must define a function for every `ID` in  of `.link` elements your page.
The `el` property of the Backbone View **MUST** be a parent of `.link`.
Inside object `{}` you need to use `:` instead `=` when you define a `variable` or a `function`, and instead you don't use `this.` prefix.
You must define new `View` (`new View`) to see the script works.

## WORKING EXAMPLE

#### JS/backbone

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : "body", //must be parent of .link elements
    events:{
        'click .link':'showDetails'
    },
    showDetails : function(e){
        console.log("event");
        var _type = $(e.target).attr("id").toUpperCase();
        var _callbackName = "show"+_type+"Details";
        this[_callbackName].call(this,e);
    },

    showAESDetails : function(e){ //an example of callback
        console.log("Hello!");
    }

    //you must define the callback of all ID
});

new View();
```

**NOTE**.

`e.target` documentation: [Here](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

`el` property documentation: [Here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)

---

### HTML

this script works with a HTML like:

```
<a class="link" id="link1" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link2" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link3" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link4" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link5" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link6" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link7" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link8" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link9" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link10" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link11" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link12" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link13" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link14" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link15" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link16" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link17" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link18" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link19" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link20" href="#">Foo</a>
<a class="link" id="link21" href="#">Foo</a>
```

The example: http://jsfiddle.net/p10masvr/6/

... Byee

Comment: I am unable to make it work. I dont know what i am missing?? http://jsfiddle.net/keshav_1007/p10masvr/1/

I m getting uncaught exception.. please let me know what i am in missing

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/p10masvr/6/ and watch my edited answer.. :)

Comment: when i implemented the above code i was getting type error $(..).attr(..) undefined. Then when i checked "var _type = $(e.target).attr("id")" is giving me empty value. But i have specified "id" in the html. But it is taking empty value. Please let me know why??

Comment: what happens if i am not using "el" property. Because if i am using that property in my code then my entire page goes blank :(

Comment: I've added two notes on the answer with reference of `e.target` and `el`.
There are a lot of ways to do what you need... This is a way, all depends to how you implement the code in your application... 
try to log with `console.log` the `e.target` maybe the value is  different to expected. 
If you not use `el` i don't know if the event list was triggered. If the `el` valued with `body` black the page probably there are some error inside render function.

Comment: yeps everything works fine.. thanks for ur help.. :)

Comment: now i am searching for extracting pdf text using javascript and i am struggling on it.. :(

Comment: any help on this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754454/how-to-use-bootstrap-mergecells-dynamically-in-backbone-js

Comment: please help me on this.. i dont know how to link you to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754454/how-to-use-bootstrap-mergecells-dynamically-in-backbone-js

Comment: i need tochange the click event to once event.. how can i change that???.. 'click .link':'showDetails' - instead of this i need to use once event how can i do that??

Comment: Hi Mate, I'm not sure to understood what u need. But: take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/p10masvr/12/ ... I edit the jsfiddle.
NB. I create a new event: `'click .link':'firstTimeOnly'` the `firstTimeOnly` handler has a `if` that check a new property `onlyone`. This prop by deafult is `false`. when u perform the `firstTimeOnly` the first time it change the prop to `true` and if u perform `firstTimeOnly` an other time it return without do nothing.

Comment: in my case if i click another link after sometime again the click event is triggering.. i dont know why?? any idea on this??

Comment: my code works only for events inside the same backbone view... if you have more than one view you need to set the variable in window context...
http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/p10masvr/13/

NB. the event was triggered every time but the handler has a check that not perform the code below the `if()` statement

Comment: let me explain clearly.. all that links which have .link class loads another view on click of that link but it takes some time to load the next view.. so i need to restrict the user not to click any other link before that other view loads.. and if i come back to the same page where links are available.. i should be able to click the links normally but during the time it takes to load the next view the i should not allow the user to click anyother link.. what shal i do??

Comment: i used window.hashchange event to set the window.onlyone = false and now it is working fine.. so now whenever i come back to that page that window.onlyone will be set to false and then the event will be triggered only once.. :) :)

Comment: yes working fine.. but how can i use that window.haschange only in a particular view.. now whenever i go back that event is triggered.. but i need to do like view specific.. how to do that??