# how to use bootstrap mergeCells dynamically in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, bootstrap-table

I have a function which creates a bootstrap table and i have to merge only specific columns in that table dynamically.

```
 this.$('#Table1').bootstrapTable({
        striped: false,
        minimumCountColumns: 2,
        smartDisplay:true,
        clickToSelect: false,
        columns:[
             {
                field:'Key2',
                title: $.t('report:'+code+'.Col2'),
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'middle', 
                sortable: true,
                events : this.linkEvents
                formatter :this.linkFormatter
             }
        ]
     });
```

linkEvent function:

```
linkEvents: {
        'onPostBody #Table1': function(e,value,row,index) {
        console.log("Inside post-body event");
        $('#Table1').bootstrapTable('mergeCells',{
        index:6,
        colspan:2
        });
        }
        }
```

even the above code doesnt working it is not coming inside the mergeCells method. Please help me on this..

Comment: @Frogmouth... Any idea on this???

Comment: any help on this?? i am stuck up here..

Comment: Some error in console? Can you reproduce the error in  http://fiddle.jshell.net/?

Comment: i will prepare and put in a fiddle and let u know.. :)

Comment: @Frogmouth : i have edited my question.. i am unable to prepare this in the fiddle.. i dont know how to get this json for the table data in the fiddle.. but i didnt get any console errors for the above code in my machine.. but the console messages inside the events itself is not coming..

Comment: `#Table1` is a child of the `$el` element of your `backbone's view`?

Comment: why property name is `linkEvents` and not `events`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80264/discussion-between-keshav1007-and-frogmouth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer with the help of @Frogmouth(really great support)..
change the code as following :

```
var keys=[];
this.$('#Table1').bootstrapTable({
        striped: false,
        minimumCountColumns: 2,
        smartDisplay:true,
        clickToSelect: false,
        columns:[
             {
                field:'Key2',
                title: $.t('report:'+code+'.Col2'),
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'middle', 
                sortable: true,
                formatter :function(value, row, index){
                           var rowValue = row.Data.Key2;
                           if(rowValue.trim()==''){ // if column value is empty those columns have to be merged
                            keys.push(index);
                           }                        
                           return row.Data.detailIndKey2;
                           }
             }
        ]
     });
```

//no need of linkEvents function. Instead use jquery

```
$(function () { 
$('#Table1').on('post-body.bs.table', function (e, data) {
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
$('#Table1').bootstrapTable('mergeCells',{
index:keys[i], //for dynamic keys
field:'Key1',
colspan:4 // how many columns have to be merged.
});
}
}); 
});
```

thanks